# How to find absolute value in C?

Tags: c, absolute-value

I need to lighten the code, and then eliminate the underlying `if` that check if the subtraction are `<0` and if the condition is true I multiply * -1 in order to have subtraction >0 (absolute value).

*I wonder if there is a function or some operator able to perform the calculation directly in **absolute value***?

```c
int i, j, N, max, s, s1;
s = v[i] - v[j];
s1 = i - j;
if (s1 < 0){
    s1 *= -1;
}
if (s < 0){
    s *= -1;
}
```

Comment: modulo or absolute value?

Comment: I cannot find a modulo or a sum in that code. Please show the real code snippet you want to "lighten".

Comment: `abs()`, `labs()` & `llabs()`.

Comment: for integers [abs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/abs) for floats [fabs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fabs)

Comment: It would be nice to see how your variables are declared and initialized.

Comment: All the variables are declared of type int

Comment: Just use the in-built functions. Or, if you're feeling brave (and `int` is 32 bits), then: `s = (s ^ (((int64_t)(s) >> 32) & 0x0FFFFFFFFll)) - (((int64_t)(s) >> 32) & 0x0FFFFFFFFll);`. Similarly for `s1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Absolute value**

To avoid `int` *overflow* of `abs(v[i] - v[j])` and its *undefined behavior* (UB) , take advantage that the `unsigned` range is very commonly twice the `int` positive range and perform *unsigned* math.

```
// int s;
unsigned s;
if (v[i] > v[j]) {
  s = 0u + v[i] - v[j];
} else {
  s = 0u + v[j] - v[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the comments say:

```
s = abs(x - y)
```

The manpage for `abs` (and also labs, llabs): https://linux.die.net/man/3/abs

It looks like you're doing this in a for loop of some sort (i,j are *hopefully* loop indices, otherwise you need to name your variables more descriptively). In that case, you should be able to architect it such that `j` is never greater than `i` for a performance increase.